# DigitalOcean MySQL connection stopped working, and cannot be restarted

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian

We're running a Digitalocean server with a Debian 8.2 distribution on it.

It has been running just fine for the longest time, until last night.

`service --status-all` doesn't even list `mysql` or `mysqld`

`which mysql` gives me the following path:
`/usr/local/bin/mysql`

`mysqladmin -u root -p status` gives the following error:

`mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.sock' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.sock' exists!`

And `/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.sock` does exist!

Mysql error logs when the problem started:
http://pastebin.com/DJtusxCc

Comment: What is the output of `sudo service mysqld status`?

Comment: See this : https://rageagainstshell.com/2015/09/mysql-innodb-checksum-mismatch/